can I convert List of String into single String using java 8 streams
I have written a below code using java.
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("book1");
list.add("book2");
list.add("book3");
list.add("book4");


String combined = "";

for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    combined = combined + (i+1)+ ". "+list.get(i)+" \r\n";
}

System.out.println(combined);

OUTPUT
1. book1 
2. book2 
3. book3 
4. book4 

How can I write this code using streams. I tried doing below:
String combined2 = "";

List<String> list2 = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).mapToObj(i->i+1+". "+list.get(i)+" \r\n").toList();


for(String s:list2) {
    combined2 = combined2+s;
}

System.out.println(combined2);

But I don't want to use for loop here. How can I improve my approach ?

A Java 22 preview Gatherer would work well here, avoiding the need to use IntStream.

You are almost there. You just need to use Stream.collect.
Here is the modified code.
String list2 = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .mapToObj(i-> i+1 + ". " + list.get(i))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

output:
1. book1
2. book2
3. book3
4. book4


Note that unlike the original, this does not add the line separator at the end of the string (which may or may not be what is actually desired).  Be sure to append it manually if the desired behavior is to have the string at the end as well, and not just in between elements: .collect([...]) + System.lineSeparator().
